# SharePoint 2013 online customize personimmersive page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, mysite

I want to customize the SharePoint 2013 online(office 365) "About me" linked page (personimmersive.aspx) to a custom look and feel.

Even clicking on any SPUser name, for ex in a list item modified by is "John Smith" if we click on it goes to about me page.

This page resides under mysite but I cannot see this page is SharePoint 2013 designer to edit, but modifying SharePoint pages in designer is not always the best way.
Can I just create a new page and redirect all Profile page request to that custom page?
IF I create app parts and edit the page I cannot edit the top portion of the page.

Answer (score 1):

redirecting may not be a feasible approach, specially on the online versions

you can try to take advantage of web parts and css to do what you can

> The biggest change is that you can’t edit the entire top portion of
>   the page. These used to be in a web part zone, and you could choose to
>   add/remove the web parts. Now they are fixed, with no ability to move
>   them around or change the parts.
>
> We had removed the Activity Feed web part previously because we were
>   using Yammer newsfeeds and group feeds embedded throughout the site,
>   and this part always showed “No activities”. Now this is back again,
>   with no way to remove it, short of editing the page in SharePoint
>   Designer.
>
> There are still web part zones on the bottom, but really the problem
>   is no control over the display of most of the top of the page.

http://weshackett.com/2014/04/office-365-new-profile-page/

Answer (score 1):

There is *personImmersive.aspx* in SharePoint Designer, you should be able to find it in All Files. Just make sure you connect to *[your_domain]-my.sharepoint.com* instead of *[your_domain].sharepoint.com*.

Answer (score 1):

you can't customize the page completely.However you can add custom web part and custom css to change the look and feel to a great extent.
@tiago duarte you can still remove the activity web part.This can be done using script editor webpart and hiding the complete block/div.